# AGI on Queue Ringing an Agent in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

We can trigger an AGI if an agent attends a call in Queue.Is it possible to trigger an AGI when an agent rings in a Queue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do agi on

1) before call other party - using AGI command

2) answer call before bridge - using M in dial command

No, not posible start agi on ringing event, but posible catch ringing event using AMI event listener and do action based on that.